# Pandas DataFrame.reset_index for columns

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a `reset_index` equivalent for the column headings? In other words, if the column names are an `MultiIndex`, how would I drop one of the levels?

Comment: drop a column, or move into the index (as a row)? I don't think there's not really a clean way to move to index aside from wrapping in .T...

Comment: The idea being to move a given level of the column names's MultiIndex to the DataFrame as a new row (or optionally just to drop it altogether).

Comment: Maybe a simpler question is how do I simply drop a level of hierarchy in the column names?

Answer (score 4):

Answer to the second question:

```
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(level)
```

First question is as @AndyHayden points out not that straight forward. It only would make sense if your columns names are of the same type as your column values.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a really dumb way to turn your columns into tuples instead:

```
df.columns = list(df.columns)
```

You can build on that to get whatever you want, for example if you had a 2 level `MultiIndex`, to remove the outermost level, you could just do:

```
df.columns = [col[1] for col in df.columns]
```

You can't do fancy indexing over the iteration because it's generating tuples, but you can do things like:

```
df.columns = MultiIndex.from_tuples([col[1:] for col in df.columns])
```

So you have some options there.

Answer (score 0):

Transpose df, reset index, and transopse again.

`df.T.reset_index().T`

Comment: You actually need `df.T.reset_index(drop=True).T` to prevent the names being reinserted as a regular column.

Comment: Also, for a large dataframe I suspect this uses a lot of memory. Wonder if that can be avoided...

Comment: As @smci pointed out, you need to drop. And this makes you loose the names of the columns so it breaks the dataframe.